# Fitting a well-specified 1D function of time to 3D spatial and spatially correlated data

Tags: spatial, fitting, curve-fitting, neuroimaging, spatial-correlation

I have acquired experimental data that can be considered to be a scalar field in physical three-dimensional space, $(x,y,z)$ that I have observed over time, measured on an equally spaced regular grid. At each point in space I have a set of measurements in time.

I have a good physical understanding of the process going on, and while I could write down a large set of PDEs to describe it, I would really rather not: the spatial part is messy and the transport terms are small. The time behaviour is well approximated by an analytical model that is frankly little more than a set of exponentials with a bit of numerical integration. In particular, I am not sure I can write it down as anything other than a continuous and differentiable function of time.

This model has some parameters, and I am interested in them. Let's call it $f(\vec{\theta},t)$, where $t$ is time, and $\vec{\theta}$ a set of parameters in the model. If I fit the dataset assuming that $\vec{\theta}=\vec{\theta}(x,y,z)$ and that each voxel is spatially independent, I get a reasonably good fit but regions where the dataset has noise and the fit doesn't work well contain "stupid" values of the parameters and the fit is poor. Worse, I know that my noise is not totally spatially independent (though it is in time).

I wish to fit a spatiotemporal model that has no or little knowledge about the spatial domain, but lets me use my knowledge of what $f(t)$ is. For example, assuming that $\vec{\theta}(x,y,z)$ is smoothly varying and approximated by splines would be fine, as my parameters are most likely spatially correlated with each other. My goal ultimately is to estimate the parameters $\vec{\theta}(x,y,z)$ as best as possible, and look at a map of them.

I am sure that this is a huge area of research and a brief search shows lots of geospatial models and spatiotemporal statistical methods exist to find neat little solutions to these sorts of problems. However, they usually don't let one have an arbitrary functional form for $f(t)$, or they assume that the timepoints come from a distribution like a gaussian process (which I don't think is the case here).

I'd love a pointer in the right direction to a set of techniques to be interested in.

A simple example dataset would be something like an inversion recovery MRI imaging dataset [obtained on a human brain](https://osf.io/tmdfu/files/osfstorage/5a0b4e9a6c613b026c4888d5) and [freely distributed](https://osf.io/cmg9z) from [qMR lab](https://qmrlab.readthedocs.io/en/master/inversion_recovery_batch.html), being fit to the model $\text{abs}\left(a+b \exp(-t/T_1)\right)$, where $a$ and $b$ can be negative, and $T_1\geq 0$ is the parameter of scientific interest – an example of the map and the resulting curve in the voxel shown by the '+' are shown below. I should stress this is *not* my problem, but sufficiently similar.

Most people in my field fit these voxels independently, despite the fact that they are spatially correlated and smoothly varying. I am convinced we can do better!

[image: The resulting T1 map]
[image: An example data curve]

Comment: Is $T_1$ varying over the field, or is it constant for the whole sample? (And are you interested in standard errors/inference on $T_1$?) If varying, I was thinking of *geographically weighted regression*, where you fit a locally weighted model at each voxel (where nearby voxels get smaller weight). This gives a smooth map, and can maybe smooth more in areas with higher variance. It is convenient way to work out model fitting for spatial data and visualize smooth functions (not so nice for inference though).

Comment: @AndyW – Thanks so much for your thoughts. Yes, $T_1$ varies over the field (it's shown in the brain image) and in a given tissue type it tends to be slightly different in regions of disease, but drastically different between different tissue types. I'm very much interested in errors on $T_1$. Geographically weighted regression sounds great and exactly what I'm interested in – particularly if it can cope with nonlinear functions of the parameters (my actual problem is the numerical solution of a 1D differential equation with parameters).

Comment: [Re $T_1$ specifically – the spatial mapping of $T_1$ in the human body is actually a fairly big field of medical research; it's related to the temperature and molecular environment of protons and you can predict it analytically for free water. It's much longer in the brain's cerebrospinal fluid compared to the white or grey matter, for example, and changes in many diseases. Essentially everyone who measures it fits voxels independently to a signal model, the simplest of which is just an exponential. The difficulty is doing this is getting the data quickly, in sick people.]